# Configuring local git with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

In our org we have locally hosted git. And for my project i need to implement CI with the help of jenkins. I know configuring jenkins with GitHub but not sure configuring it with local git.

In `Repository URL` what should i have to provide?

after running `git remote show origin`

command in my repository i got something like below

```
WARNING: previous mirror push of repo 'OPT' to host 'tregit1' failed, status is:
2017-06-16.19:28:39     31417   ssh: connect to host 10.9.100.31 port 22: No route to host
2017-06-16.19:28:39     31417   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
2017-06-16.19:28:39     31417
2017-06-16.19:28:39     31417   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
2017-06-16.19:28:39     31417   and the repository exists.
----------
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: gitbox:OPT
  Push  URL: gitbox:OPT
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

and for running this `git remote -v` command the output was like

```
origin  gitbox:OPT (fetch)
origin  gitbox:OPT (push)
```

I tried to give `Repository URL` as `gitbox:OPT` but Jenkins is giving below error once i typed `gitbox:OPT`

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h gitbox:OPT HEAD" 
returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitbox: Temporary failure in name resolution 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

can anyone tell me what to provide in Git URL?

Comment: Try to provide a url having the following format :  `git@hostname:repo_name.git` and before doing that, ensure to configure the git credentials (via the Credentials Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Simple: when given an alias, ssh will look for `%HOME%/.ssg/config`.

As in "`config`", not "`conf`".

Make sure `HOME` is defined (to  `C:\Users\AY`). And that your ssh config file is named "`config`".

Also test if `ssh -i C:\Users\AY\.ssh\anish -T gitolite@10.47.52.185` does work.

> I have used the `gitolite.pub` from ubuntu, I created `anish.pub` in windows and added this to gitolite and changed `conf/gitolite.conf` as shown below repo

```
gitolite-admin RW+ = gitolite 
repo testing 
  RW+ = @all 
repo bigfastblog 
  RW+ = anish
```

Make sure to push that gitolite.conf back to the Ubuntu server, and check that `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys` does list `anish.pub` content.
Also Windows `HOME/.ssh` should include `anish.pub` and `anish` (the private key)

> Finally able to clone: It is problem with `HOME` environment variable.

Comment: Its not just for testing. I need to configure with Poll SCM as well.

Comment: I have clearly gave you the logs which i got. Its not the `Github`. We have installed git locally with the help of gitbox. Just by giving `gitbox:OPT` its showing error

Comment: @Ben.Bean, Sorry to misinterpretation, Updated the answer, Kindly check & Revert.